# Regular expression to exclude some HTML tags in Postgresql

Tags: regex, postgresql, regex-negation

Is there a way to maintain some tags and the text between tags, excluding tags not wanted from an HTML text using regular expressions in Postgresql?
I'd like to use regexp_replace because regexp_matches results in a set of array that slow down the query when I use in a very long text.

I manage to match the tags that I want to preserve. For example:

```
select regexp_replace(
'<diversity bad text> <div good text> <br> <invalid> </div> mantain1 <division> mantain2 </invalid> mantain3',
E'</?(div|br)( [^>]*?>|>)', 'OUT','gi');
```

Results:

```
<diversity bad text> OUT OUT <invalid> OUT mantain1 <division> mantain2 </invalid> mantain3
```

But when I try to invert the match, the things go out of control.

The closest I got using negative lookahead is:

```
select regexp_replace(
'<diversity bad text> <div good> <br> <invalid> </div> mantain1 <division> mantain2 </invalid> mantain3',
E'<(?!div|br)(.+?)>', 'OUT','gi');
```

Results:

```
<diversity bad text> <div good text> <br> OUT OUT mantain1 <division> mantain2 OUT mantain3
```

But obviously not I wanted.

The expected results for the text:

```
<diversity bad text> <div good> <br> <invalid> </div> mantain1 <division> mantain2 </invalid> mantain3
```

is:

```
OUT <div good> <br> OUT </div> mantain1 OUT mantain2 OUT mantain3
```

Comment: [Regex might not be the best tool for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: What is the expected result? Try `E'\\s*<(?!/?(div|br)\\y)[^>]*>'`

Comment: That's great Wiktor. It works perfectly. I edited the post to include the expected results.